# Погрешность вычисления в MySql при действии со значениями столбцов

Tags: mysql, float, double

Есть БД, в ней таблица со столбцами:

```
| quantity | price | discount | *(количество|цена|скидка)
```

при пересчёте сумм с учётом скидки получаются суммы:

```
mysql_query(
  "SELECT
     SUM(price * quantity) AS summ
   FROM
     custom_item
   WHERE
     id_custom='$zakaz'",
   $db);    

12 | 189.00 | 0%  | = 2268.00       
12 | 153.12 | 0%  | = 1837.44  
24 | 110.89 | 15% | = 2262.24
```

Всё отлично работает. Но нужно подсчитать сумму всех заказов, и я сделал так:

```
mysql_query(
    "SELECT SUM(
            (price * quantity)-(price * quantity * (discount/100))
        ) AS summ 
        FROM custom_item
        WHERE id_custom='$zakaz'",
    $db
)
```

Вот только при пересчёте на калькуляторе получается так:

2268.00 + 1837.44 + 2262.24 = **6367.68**,

а когда считает mysql = **6367.5959**, округляю функцией

```
number_format($myro2['0'], 2, '.', '');
```

и получаю **6367.60**. В чём дело, друзья, как решить вопрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эх, школа... математика... С первыми двумя строками всё ясно, а вот третья:

```
1) 24 * 110.89 = 2661.36 (сумма без скидки)
2) 2661.36 / 100 * 15 = 399.204 (скидка)
3) 2661.36 - 399.204 = 2262.156 (итоговая сумма)
```

Теперь суммируем всё вместе:

```
2268.00 + 1837.44 + 2262.156 = 6367.596
```

[Запускаем ваш запрос](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8040bc/1/0) практически без редактирование и видим **6367.596**. А калькулятор ваш "фтопку" надо ;)

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Всё оказалось намного проще, чем казалось... Частенько предполагаешь более сложное решение, а ответы бывают и на поверхности.

Comment: @cheh1, не за что. Только вот я забыл акцентировать внимание на том, что для поля "**price**", я использовал тип не **float**, а **decimal**. Хотя, если вы смотрели [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8040bc/1/0), то наверняка заметили это.

Answer (score 2):

Не следует использовать для денежных и количественных величин числа с плавающей запятой. Используйте `DECIMAL`.